# JSONDecoder - decoding string values to correct types

Tags: swift, decodable

I'm consuming a JSON api that returns every field as a string. However some of those string values actually represent a timestamp and a longitude and latitude (as separate fields).

If I specify these values as a `Date` and `Double`s respectively it swift throws an error `Expected to decode Double but found a string`

```
Struct Place {
    var created_at: Date?
    var longitude: Double?
    var latitude: Double?

}
```

I've seen some examples that seem to deal with Date formatting online, but I'm unsure what to do around the Double values?

I tried overriding `init(from decoder:Decoder)` but this still doesn't give the correct values:

e.g

```
init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    longitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude) //returns nil but using String works fine
}
```

I know I can extract the string and convert to a double like:

```
  longitude = Double(try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .longitude))
```

But is there another way?

Furthermore, I actually have a number of other properties that convert fine, but by doing this work around for these 3 properties, I now have to add all the other properties in there which seems a bit redundant. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON value is `String` you have to decode `String`. An implicit type conversion from `String` to `Double` is not possible.

You can avoid a custom initializer by adding a computed variable `coordinate`, in this case the `CodingKeys` are required

```
import CoreLocation

struct Place : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case createdAt = "created_at", longitude, latitude}

    let createdAt: Date
    let longitude: String
    let latitude: String

    var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(latitude) ?? 0.0, longitude: Double(longitude) ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like I still need the custom init for the date unfortunately as that is also a string. But I like this computed property for the coordinate

Comment: You can add a [date decoding strategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy) to decode the `String` to `Date`